# angular 2 XMLHttpRequest cannot load Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400

Tags: apache, angular

Have enabled CORS for enabling requests between my angular2 and magento.

For which i need to change the apache server settings of my magento.

I have added below lines to enable OPTIONS request in htaccess file of apache.

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
....

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
```

This is how i calling my rest api in angular 2:

```
export class ProductService {
public _productUrl = 'http://10..../Mage_ang2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1';

constructor(private _http: Http) { }

getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ntthnrbj1uam2tuv1ekva7n8jh18mcnkby3');
let options = new RequestOptions( {method: RequestMethod.Get, headers: headers });


console.log(headers);
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl,options)
        .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

If i run my angular2, i get :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.2..../Magento2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400

What is the correct way to get response from other domain to my angular allowing CORS with the above settings?